# Xamarin.forms Masterpage and MVVM Concept

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin.forms, I am developing a multiple page app(Android, iOS, windows) that has a common design on most of the pages.

**The .net framework has masterpage concept, is it available in Xamarin.forms as well?**

Also whats the best coding style for Xamarin.forms? I have read it should be MVVM architecure. I have never used MVVM architecture. So if possible can anyone help me understanding MVVM in Xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 2):

MVVM is a Microsoft pattern that you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel or google away.

Xamarin Forms XAML however isn't exactly like WPF XAML so be aware differences will occur.

This is a blog post that goes through an MVVM pattern Xamarin Forms app, using MVVM Light. http://www.xamarinhelp.com/14-days-to-building-an-enterprise-quality-xamarin-forms-app/

Its a huge topic but it will point you in the right direction. Then any further questions asked can be a little more specific as this question is a bit too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way,You can use FreshMVVM (MVVM Designed for Xamarin.Forms)

There are masterdetailpage related concept with this framework,too

https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm

http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/xamarinforms-mvvm-first-freshmvvm-application/